# electron-builder fails on macOS building nsis and appImage

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder, appimage, macos-sonoma

I'm working on the latest MacBook Intel Pro with macOS Sonoma 14.0.

At the moment I try to build an electron app for mac .dmg, win .nsis and linux .appImage.

macOS ... no problems.

Windows ... I found out that macOS since macOS xxx doesn't support 32 bit apps. The .nsis however builds an 32/64-bit version which therefore doesn't work on the windows machines.  So I have to build it on windows itself. That works.

The linux version is meant for Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit. The AppImage can be built on my macBook using `electron-builder --armv7l`. Setting the executable rights in properties to "all" the AppImage is executable but no app will be installed on the Raspberry Pi.

I do not know how to solve this. I need exactly these three formats to use the auto-updater included in electron-builder.

What am I doing wrong? Does anybody have any advices or snippets for me? In a first step I need the linux version. Second, building all versions on my macBook would be great.